# How to get WHERE clause to stop multiplying values in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to see which work orders are within 15% of budget or over. Currently, I have this:

```
fnd.sort_code, 
phs.shop,
SUM ( fnd.amount ) AS 'Spent', 
CAST(phs.budget AS Decimal(9,2)) AS 'Budget'
FROM dbo.ae_p_phs_e phs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ae_s_fnd_a fnd ON (phs.proposal=fnd.proposal AND phs.sort_code=fnd.sort_code) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ae_p_pro_e pro ON (phs.proposal=pro.proposal)
WHERE
ROUND(CAST(fnd.amount / phs.budget AS Decimal(9,3)), 3) >= 0.85 
AND
pro.status_code = 'OPEN'
AND
phs.budget > 0
GROUP BY fnd.proposal, fnd.sort_code, phs.shop, phs.budget
ORDER BY fnd.proposal ASC
```

It seems to return work orders, but when I validate them against the database, the "fnd.amount" column seems to be multiplied by 2, 3, 4 and sometimes 5x. I noticed that if I remove the ROUND/CAST statement from the WHERE clause, it will return the work orders with their proper values.

Any idea why my filtering is multiplying only one of my SELECT statements?

UPDATE:
By request,

[image]

Basically if a query returns the example set above, I would like the query in question to return only those that meet the 0.85 or above threshold (those highlighted in yellow).

Comment: Please provide sample data, actual results and desired results (for a minimal example - we don't need your production query). Most likely issue without investigating is that your joins are duplicating you base rows, hence the multiplication.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry, usually if I don't post my query/code I get banned or yelled at so I posted it out of habit. I'll update with some examples/desired results.

Comment: We definitely need your query, but you should be creating a [mre] i.e. the smallest example which still demonstrates your issue. Frequently in creating such an example you will identify and solve the issue yourself.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Have you tried to run your query without the `SUM` clause to see the detail of what is returning?

Comment: Also: What are the datatypes of `phs.budget` and `fnd.amount`? Why are you casting `phs.budget` both your `SELECT` and the division of both in your `WHERE`?

Comment: @JoshPart I just tried that - it does give a breakdown however it's pulling numbers that I cannot find in the database nor can I achieve those numbers by adding/multiplying other numbers associated with the work order. I see two different work orders that are inflating these numbers

Comment: @JoshPart They are decimals. However in the DB, the "fnd.amount" only goes 2 decimal places while the "phs.budget" goes 5 decimal places. So I cast it in the SELECT statement to make it easier to read. Then I cast again in the WHERE three decimal places to make sure it is rounding to the nearest hundredth

Comment: Did you also remove the `GROUP BY` clause? My guess is that your `JOIN`s are causing those orders to be returned 2 or more times

Comment: @JoshPart I did - still pulling strange numbers. I guess I could play around with my joins. I'm not sure where to start but at 5 hours in on this problem I'll try all of them

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky without knowing what your table names actually mean but assuming that phs is the "Work order" then you probably want to apply that 85% to the total Spent with the budget instead of the individual components of that total

So try replacing the where condition (That's applied before the aggregation)

```
WHERE
ROUND(CAST(fnd.amount / phs.budget AS Decimal(9,3)), 3) >= 0.85
```

with a a having clause (Applied after the aggregation)

```
HAVING
ROUND(CAST(SUM( fnd.amount ) / phs.budget AS Decimal(9,3)), 3) >= 0.85
```

Personally I'd write that more like this

```
HAVING SUM(fnd.amount) >= (phs.budget * 0.85)
```

But that's a style choice, either will work

Also there's no point in having left joins to tables that you're going to apply filters on

So that all leaves your final query looking something like this

```
select
fnd.sort_code, 
phs.shop,
SUM ( fnd.amount ) AS 'Spent', 
CAST(phs.budget AS Decimal(9,2)) AS 'Budget'
FROM dbo.ae_p_phs_e phs 
JOIN dbo.ae_s_fnd_a fnd ON (phs.proposal=fnd.proposal AND phs.sort_code=fnd.sort_code) 
JOIN dbo.ae_p_pro_e pro ON (phs.proposal=pro.proposal)
WHERE pro.status_code = 'OPEN'
AND phs.budget > 0
GROUP BY fnd.proposal, fnd.sort_code, phs.shop, phs.budget
HAVING SUM(fnd.amount) >= (phs.budget * 0.85) 
ORDER BY fnd.proposal ASC
```